# How to use rails activerecord to write a query with 3 conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to create the following ruby on rails 3 query:

User.rb

```
search_results = self.find( :all,
                    :select => 'id,fb_id,fname,lname,org_id',
                    :conditions => ["guest = ? AND fb_id != ? AND trim(lower(fname)) || ' ' || trim(lower(lname)) LIKE ?", false, nil, '%'+"#{q.downcase}"+'%'],
                    :limit => 8
)
```

Conditions being:

1. User needs to be either guest == false or have a fb_id that's not null
2. If 1 is true, then find based on the user.fname and user.lname

This is returning nothing. I'm guessing I'm messing up with #1. Any suggestions on what's wrong with the condition or a better way to handle this query? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the log to see exactly what the query to the database is. Ensure that there really are the records in the db that you think there are.

If the request is `User needs to be either guest == false or have a fb_id that's not null` then the query should be

```
q2 = "%#{q.downcase}%"
search_results = self.find( :all,
                :select => 'id,fb_id,fname,lname,org_id',
                :conditions => 
  ["(guest = ? OR fb_id is not null) AND (
    trim(lower(fname)) LIKE ? OR
    trim(lower(lname)) LIKE ?)",  
    false, q2, q2],
   :limit => 8
)
```

**Edited** I left out the not in the null test. I also improved the setting of q2. I followed mu's suggestion on handling dbms-specific false constants.

Answer (score 1):

I would break it into three named scopes, i.e. something like (in the model):

```
scope :guest = self.find_by_guest(id)  
scope :fb = self.find_by_fb_id(fb_id)  
scope :name_check = self.find("trim(lower(fname)) || ' ' || trim(lower(lname)) LIKE ?", q.downcase)
```

(no need for those "%'s" with rails and like).

then you can chain these together as in `User.guest(guest_id).fb(fb_id).name_check(:username)`
or separately as in `User.name_check`

Then you can mix and match at will and find what works and what doesn't.